# Google Tag Manager snippet

Tags: drupal-8

I was trying to add google tag manager snippet to a drupal 8 page and having some difficulty to add the header tag on a specific page.How to add google tag manager snippet to a specific Drupal 8 page?

Answer (score 0):

May I know where are you adding the snippet? is the code included in html.html.twig?
If so, please declare a variable for the specific page content type in .theme file and use the same in html.html.twig for writing an if condition to include the GTM snippet in that page only.